NG0203: Inject() must be called from an injection context. Angular v19.0.1
As seen, receiving the common angular bug for injection contexts. Tried to get all the various angular component packages to be on v19.0.1 but some kind of mismatch is still persisting. Have tried various other solutions like persistsymlinks: true, overrides for the packages, removal of ambigious paths, etc. I have a feeling it's due to angular/materials as thats what npm ls @angular/core shows.
My package.json:
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "tailwind": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./src/output.css",
    "tailwind:watch": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./src/output.css --watch",
    "dev": "npm run tailwind:watch & ng serve"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "19.0.1",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.46.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "supabase": "^1.223.10",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^19.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^19.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "19.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.4.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.15",
    "typescript": "~5.6.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@angular/material": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "19.0.1"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "@angular/core": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "19.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "19.0.1",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": {
      "@supabase/auth-js": "2.61.0"
    }
  }
}

My supabase service.ts:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import {
  AuthChangeEvent,
  AuthError,
  AuthSession,
  createClient,
  Session,
  SupabaseClient,
  User,
} from '@supabase/supabase-js';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment'
import { Database } from '../types/database.types';
import { Observable, Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export interface Profile {
  id?: string
  avatar_url: string
}

export interface Destination {
  id: number;
  Destination: string;
  Region: string;
  Country: string;
  Description?: string;
  Latitude?: number;
  Longitude?: number;
  Best_time_to_visit?: string;
  Average_temperature?: number;
}

export interface DestinationList {
  id?: number;
  user_id: string;
  name: string;
  description?: string;
  is_public: boolean;
  destinations: string[];
  created_at: Date;
  updated_at: Date;
}

export interface DestinationListWithDetails extends DestinationList {
  destinations_details?: Destination[]; // Full destination details
}

export interface ListReview {
  id?: number;
  list_id: number;
  user_id: string;
  username: string;
  rating: number;
  comment: string;
  created_at: Date;
}


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SupabaseService {
  private supabase: SupabaseClient;
  // using a subject here, emits observables and can receive observables
  private authSubject = new Subject<{ event: string, session: Session | null }>();

  constructor() {
    this.supabase = createClient<Database>(environment.supabaseUrl, environment.supabaseKey, {
      auth: {
        persistSession: true
      }
    }); 
    // auth change listener
    this.supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
      this.authSubject.next({ event, session });
    });
  }
  
  async getSession(): Promise<{ data: { session: Session | null }; error: AuthError | null }> {
    return this.supabase.auth.getSession();
  }

  profile(user: User) {
    return this.supabase
      .from('profiles')
      .select(`username, website, avatar_url`)
      .eq('id', user.id)
      .single()
  }

  async searchDestinations(name: string = '', region: string = '', country: string = '', resultLimit: number = 5) {
    try {
      console.log('Search parameters:', { name, region, country });
      let query = this.supabase.from('Destinations').select('*');
  
      // reject empty fields from the search
      if (name && name.trim() !== '') {
        query = query.ilike('Destination', `${name.trim()}%`);
      }
    
      if (region && region.trim() !== '') {
        query = query.ilike('Region', `${region.trim()}%`);
      }
    
      if (country && country.trim() !== '') {
        query = query.ilike('Country', `${country.trim()}%`);
      } 
  
      query = query.limit(resultLimit); // limit the number of results shown

      const { data, error } = await query;
      console.log('basic query:', await query);
      console.log('Query Results:', data);
    if (error) {
      console.error('Query Error:', error);
    }

      return { data, error }; // Ensure you're returning an object
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Unexpected error in searchDestinations:', err);
      return { data: null, error: err };
    }
  }

  // emit observable authcange events
  authChanges(): Observable<{ event: AuthChangeEvent; session: Session | null }> {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      const { data: { subscription } } = this.supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
        observer.next({ event, session });
      });
  
      // Cleanup: Unsubscribe when the observer unsubscribes
      return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
  }

  async getCurrentUser(): Promise<User | null> {
    const { data } = await this.getSession();
    return data.session?.user || null;
  }

  async getCurrentUserId(): Promise<string | null> {
    const user = await this.getCurrentUser();
    return user?.id || null;
  }

  async getCurrentUsername(): Promise<string | null> {
    const user = await this.getCurrentUser();
    return user?.email?.split('@')[0] || null; // Fallback to email username
  }

  signIn(email: string) {
    return this.supabase.auth.signInWithOtp({ email })
  }

  signOut() {
    return this.supabase.auth.signOut();
  }

  updateProfile(profile: Profile) {
    const update = {
      ...profile,
      updated_at: new Date(),
    }

    return this.supabase.from('profiles').upsert(update)
  }

  downLoadImage(path: string) {
    return this.supabase.storage.from('avatars').download(path)
  }

  uploadAvatar(filePath: string, file: File) {
    return this.supabase.storage.from('avatars').upload(filePath, file)
  }


  // *** User list creation *** //
  async createDestinationList(list: Partial<DestinationList>): Promise<{ data: DestinationList | null, error: any }> {
    // Validate required attributes
    if (!list.name || !list.user_id) {
      return { data: null, error: 'Name and user_id are required' };
    }

    // Check if user already has a list with this name
    const { data: existingLists, error: checkError } = await this.supabase
      .from('destination_lists')
      .select('*')
      .eq('user_id', list.user_id)
      .eq('name', list.name)
      .single();

    if (existingLists) {
      return { data: null, error: 'A list with this name already exists' };
    }

    // Check if user has reached the maximum number of lists
    const { count, error: countError } = await this.supabase
      .from('destination_lists')
      .select('*', { count: 'exact' })
      .eq('user_id', list.user_id);

    if (count && count >= 20) {
      return { data: null, error: 'Maximum number of lists (20) reached' };
    }

    // Prepare list data
    const listToCreate = {
      user_id: list.user_id,
      name: list.name,
      description: list.description || null,
      is_public: false, // Default to private
      destinations: list.destinations || [],
      created_at: new Date(),
      updated_at: new Date()
    };

    // Insert the list
    const { data, error } = await this.supabase
      .from('destination_lists')
      .insert(listToCreate)
      .select()
      .single();

    return { data, error };
  }


  async getUserLists(userId: string): Promise<{ data: DestinationList[] | null, error: any }> {
    const { data, error } = await this.supabase
      .from('destination_lists')
      .select('*')
      .eq('user_id', userId);

    return { data, error };
  }

  // Add these additional methods for list management
  async getListDetails(listId: number, userId: string): Promise<{ data: DestinationListWithDetails | null, error: any }> {
    const { data, error } = await this.supabase
      .from('destination_lists')
      .select(`
        *,
        destinations(*)
      `)
      .eq('id', listId)
      .eq('user_id', userId)
      .single();

    return { data, error };
  }

  async updateDestinationList(listId: number, userId: string, updates: Partial<DestinationList>): Promise<{ data: DestinationList | null, error: any }> {
    // Validate user ownership
    const { data: existingList, error: checkError } = await this.supabase
      .from('destination_lists')
      .select('*')
      .eq('id', listId)
      .eq('user_id', userId)
      .single();

    if (!existingList) {
      return { data: null, error: 'List not found or unauthorized' };
    }

    // Validate destination existence if destinations are being modified
    if (updates.destinations) {
      for (const destination of updates.destinations) {
        const { data: destCheck } = await this.searchDestinations(destination);
        if (!destCheck || destCheck.length === 0) {
          return { data: null, error: `Destination ${destination} does not exist` };
        }
      }
    }

    const updateData = {
      ...updates,
      updated_at: new Date()
    };

    const { data, error } = await this.supabase
      .from('destination_lists')
      .update(updateData)
      .eq('id', listId)
      .select()
      .single();

    return { data, error };
  }


  async deleteDestinationList(listId: number, userId: string): Promise<{ success: boolean, error: any }> {
    const { error } = await this.supabase
      .from('destination_lists')
      .delete()
      .eq('id', listId)
      .eq('user_id', userId);

    return { 
      success: !error, 
      error 
    };
  }


  // *** List reviews *** //
  async addListReview(review: Partial<ListReview>): Promise<{ data: ListReview | null, error: any }> {
    // Validate review data
    if (!review.list_id || !review.user_id || !review.rating) {
      return { data: null, error: 'Missing required review information' };
    }
  
    const reviewToCreate = {
      ...review,
      created_at: new Date()
    };
  
    const { data, error } = await this.supabase
      .from('list_reviews')
      .insert(reviewToCreate)
      .select()
      .single();
  
    return { data, error };
  }
  
  async getListReviews(listId: number): Promise<{ data: ListReview[] | null, error: any }> {
    const { data, error } = await this.supabase
      .from('list_reviews')
      .select('*')
      .eq('list_id', listId)
      .order('created_at', { ascending: false });
  
    return { data, error };
  }
}

npm ls @angular/core:
 npm ls @angular/core
+-- @angular/material@19.0.1
| +-- @angular/animations@19.0.1
| | `-- @angular/core@19.0.1 deduped
| +-- @angular/cdk@19.0.1
| | `-- @angular/core@19.0.1 deduped
| +-- @angular/common@19.0.1
| | `-- @angular/core@19.0.1 deduped
| +-- @angular/core@19.0.1
| +-- @angular/forms@19.0.1
| | `-- @angular/core@19.0.1 deduped
| `-- @angular/platform-browser@19.0.1
|   `-- @angular/core@19.0.1 deduped
`-- @auth0/auth0-angular@2.2.3
  +-- @angular/core@19.0.1 deduped
  `-- @angular/router@19.0.1
    `-- @angular/core@19.0.1 deduped

Expecting to be able to use the component in my project without the error being thrown. Have tried: aligning package versions, various config settings, delete and redownload node_modules, shrinkwrap packages to ensure correct version.

Do you use any effect or computed signal in your project ? It looks like an issue when you try to run it outside of injection context with effect

I have one computed signal but it's in a different component so I don't think it's causing the issue?

Try to find and remove one by one the use of effect or computed in your app and test

Wow, that's crazy, deleting the computed signal solved the issue. Thank you Raphael!!! Do you know why that was causing the issue? Was it because computed signals rely on a different version of angular that isn't supported fully by the inject?

The fix for myself was as user Raphael VO said, to delete the computed signals. Issue was due to library using a different version of Angular...
